# communicate between two modules nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Hello i am trying to emit command using ***SOCKET*** to user when setting gets changed through some ***API***.. 
**but I dont know how can i get socket or tell socket to emit the message to user..**
Please Help

this is my code

```js
//Socket INIT
  
class Socket{
 constructor(){
    
 //Init variables
  }
  start(){
 //Start socket
   this.io.use((socket, next) => this.auth.authDevice(socket, next));
  this.io.on('connection',(socket) => this.conn.handleConn(socket));

  }
  
}

//Socket Connection
let socketStack = [];
class Connection{
   handleConn(socket){
     //  store client 
     socketStack[socket.userid] = socket
   }
    pushCmd(userid, command){
      //cheeck if userid exists in >>socketStack<<  and emit 
    }
 }

//Command Emit 
class Command {
  constructor(id) {
    this.userid = id.userid
    //socket - Connection class
    this.socketConn = new SocketHandler()
  }
  static push(userid, command) {
    
    //i want to sent it to current socket context. this has empty socketStack..
  this.socketConn.pushCmd(userid, command);
  }
}
let socket = new Socket();


socket.start() //connection started, all clients connect to //this  socket .. I WANT API to use this socket to emit something that //API sends....
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to make socket to 'listen' on server. For example, I'm using express with node.js, and this is the way I run socket.io:

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var io = socketio.listen(server);

io.on('connect', function (socket) {
    socket.on('exampleCall', function () {
        console.log("socket invoked!");
        socket.emit("exampleEmit");
    });
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function () {
var addr = server.address();
console.log("Server listening at", addr.address + ":" + addr.port);
});
```

Comment: Hi, i did all that it in Socket class's constructor.i didnt just mention it  bcz it would make the code more difficult to read